# How get photo url in prestashop 1.5.4.1

Tags: url, photo

How I get photo url in prestashop 1.5.4.1 when I run the code on the other server using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

In mysl is not possible, try PHP width:

```
$ link = new Link ();
$ link-> getImageLink ('nameofproduct', $ id_product .'_ '. $ image_id, $ image_type);
```